# Get and Set Java into Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, class, parameters, constructor

I'm currently learning OOP in ruby language but I'm having some trouble to understand constructor concepts. So I was trying to convert one code that I did in java into ruby. Take a look:

Java code:

```
public class Test {
       public Test(int[][] array) {
           this.array= array;
      }
       public int[][] getTest() {
           return array;
      }
    }
```

Ruby code:

```
class Test
  def Test(*array)
    @test = test
  end 
  def getTest()
    return array
  end 
end
```

Is it right? Or should I use initialize class? Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Object_Oriented_Programming

Comment: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `array` in `getTest` is a local variable. I have a feeling you want to return the variable that was set in the `test` method (You can't capitalize method names without `define_method`, but that's another story). Ruby also has shortcuts for this. Here are a couple ways you could to it:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :test
end
my_test = Test.new
my_test.test = "Hello Test"
my_test.test #=> "Hello Test"
```

The above example uses the built in `attr_accessor` method to define a setter and a getter method for that variable.

```
class Test
  def test(value)
    @test = value
  end
  def getTest
    @test
  end
end
```

This one is the exact same as `attr_accessor` but it's slightly slower and the getter method is renamed to `getTest`.

Or, if you want it to be a constructor:

```
class Test
  def initialize(test)
    @test = test
  end
  def getTest
    @test
  end
end
```

And lastly, if you actually want the capitalized method name:

```
class Test
  define_method(:Test) do |test|
    @test = test
  end
  def getTest
    @test
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Java code:

```
public class Test {
   private int[][] array; // you need to explicitly declare this

   public Test(int[][] array) {
      this.array = array;
   }

   public int[][] getTest() {
       return array;
   }
}
```

Ruby code:

```
class Test
  #implicitly declares a getter method 'array' that returns @array field
  attr_reader :array

  # constructor. Test.new(array) to invoke
  def initialize(*array)
    @array = array # sets value to the private fiend @array
  end 
end
```